# How to delete combine duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

i have got problem

[image]

I have to delete duplicates from column 3, but only when column 1 is the same, and sum value duplicates.

Thanks for answers

Comment: And what did you find so far researching?

Comment: I only find macros which delete duplicates from 2 columns, anything with 3 columns. I am not programmer, but I need so much somthing like this.

Comment: In that case I'm sorry, but this isn't a free coding website. People post here when stuck in code/formula's but in your case I would suggest looking into learning or hiring.

Comment: You could easily record a Macro to do this.  Read the code that the Macro Recorder generates, and you'll learn a lot from this kind of exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastrowA As Long, LastrowF, i As Long, y As Long, j As Long
    Dim Ad_Desc As String
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim Exist As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastrowA
            Ad_Desc = .Range("A" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i).Value
            Total = .Range("B" & i).Value

            If i = 2 Then
                For y = i + 1 To LastrowA
                    If .Range("A" & y).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & y).Value = Ad_Desc Then
                        Total = Total + .Range("B" & y).Value
                    End If
                Next y

                    LastrowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range("F" & LastrowF + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                    .Range("G" & LastrowF + 1).Value = Total
                    .Range("H" & LastrowF + 1).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value


                    arr = Array(Ad_Desc)

            Else
                Exist = False
                For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                    If arr(j) = Ad_Desc Then
                        Exist = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        Exist = False
                    End If
                Next j

                If Exist = False Then

                    For y = i + 1 To LastrowA
                        If .Range("A" & y).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & y).Value = Ad_Desc Then
                            Total = Total + .Range("B" & y).Value
                        End If
                    Next y

                    LastrowF = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
                    .Range("F" & LastrowF + 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
                    .Range("G" & LastrowF + 1).Value = Total
                    .Range("H" & LastrowF + 1).Value = .Range("C" & i).Value

                    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) + 1)
                        arr(UBound(arr)) = Ad_Desc

                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Glad to hear that i help.

Answer (score 0):

I entered your sample data in the range A20:C29. Then I created a helper column with the formula below.

```
=SUMIFS($B$20:$B$29,$A$20:$A$29,$A20,$C$20:$C$29,$C20)
```

Copy the helper column to the Clipboard and PasteSpecial > Values (to replace the formulas with the result values).

Then cut/paste the helper column into column B and *Remove Duplicates* based on columns A and C.

Comment: It worked for me. Why do you think it can't do the same for you?

Comment: I don't know why, i use 2010

Comment: I use Excel 2010, too. Did you copy your data to A20:C29? The formula won't work if they are in A2:C11 unless you tweak the references.